# iOS iCloud document change notification

Tags: swift, notifications, icloud-drive, ubiquitycontainer

Can you, in Swift get a change notification when a document in the apps's iCloud Drive container changes?
For example I am testing a simple concept where I am storing all app data as a json string in the app's iCloud Drive container and I am loading it when the app launches.  I can retrieve and save the json string on demand on multiple devices, but I am wondering if there is a way to get a change notification sent to an app when the file is changed on another device.
If so, some direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UIDocument`, you can register for `UIDocumentStateChangedNotification` (for a particular document), otherwise if you are looking for changes in the App's iCloud container you need to use `NSMetaDataQuery` which is described in **Discovering an App's Documents** in [Document-Based App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH4-SW1)